# Powershell -recurese script failing to search all files in sub-directory

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am new to using powershell and I have run into a road block. I am trying to get my script to search for all new files (dated the previous night) and copy them to a test folder. This script first maps to the location where all the SQL BAK files located. The next thing that should happen is to search for all new BAK files dated the previous night and copy them to a test folder. However it is only copying one file only which is dated several days ago.

```
 $bak_path = "\\nas2\sqlbackups"

 get-childitem -path $bak_path -Filter "*.bak" -recurse | 
     where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | 
     sort-object -Property $_.CreationTime | 
     select-object -last 1 | copy-item -Destination I:\test
```

When I run this script as follows it returns all the BAK files. This tells me that that the filter is working correctly. I have other files (*.log, *.rpt) in the same location which I did not want to retrieve.

```
 $bak_path = "\\nas2\sqlbackups"
 get-childitem -path $bak_path -Filter "*.bak" -recurse
```

When I change this script to look directly into a folder with many SQL BAK  files it works!

```
 $bak_path = "\\nas2\sqlbackups\SERVER123\Database\FULL"

get-childitem -path $bak_path -Filter "*.bak" | 
    where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | 
    sort-object -Property $_.CreationTime | 
    select-object -last 1 | copy-item -Destination I:\test
```

However when I tried to use the -recurse option my script fails.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using this:

```
sort-object -Property CreationTime
```

Instead of:

```
sort-object -Property $_.CreationTime
```

Compare:

```
get-childitem -path $bak_path -Filter "*.bak" -File | 
sort-object -Property $_.CreationTime |
select-object Name, CreationTime
```

To:

```
get-childitem -path $bak_path -Filter "*.bak" -File | 
sort-object -Property CreationTime |
select-object Name, CreationTime
```